# Can't import shaders/textures to Godot from Blender 2.8

Tags: shaders, textures, blender, godot

[I'm using this shader](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hp4V-9oFmnM) for my models and then i [import them like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grPbk-bfMO4)

This is the original model in blender:
[image: godot]

the result in godot:
[image]

I think i might have missed some step but not sure of which one, i followed the tutorial video on how to import and other similar guides but the results is the same. **Any ideas of what i'm doing wrong?**
Looks like my model not importing shader and textures cor

Comment: As a general rule, materials from 3D authoring programs do not import into game engines. Each 3D authoring tool uses its own material system, often designed for offline rendering, so they don't match up in a 1:1 translatable way with the real-time rendering systems used in game engines. You'll almost always have to create a new material setup in your game engine, unless you're using special middleware designed to give a common material structure in both programs.

Comment: There is way too use those materials/shaders as is with a plugin/addon/ another program?

Comment: Very likely no, or at least not exactly. Game engine renderers are not the same, so they will not produce exactly the same output. What you probably want to ask instead is "How do I create a material effect similar to this in Godot?"